# How to decode a nested JSON file into a swift class with an unowned property

Tags: json, swift, codable

I have a custom model with several classes that I've written in Swift for a document-based Mac app. As the user inputs data to their document, instances of one class `Itinerary` are created and stored within an array which is a property of another "root" object of a different class `Course`. On top of that, multiple courses can be created and are stored in an array in the app’s Document class. I'd like the user to be able to save their data and load it back up again at a later point. So I'm attempting to implement the Codable protocol on my custom types.

The Encodable conformance works fine; when I attempt to save, the desired JSON file is produced. The problem comes when decoding.

When attempting to decode each itinerary, its `course` property needs to be set before the end of initialization because it was defined as an unowned var that points back to the course it belong's to. The place where that happens is within the course's `addItinerary(_:)` func, which is called from directly within the Itinerary's designated initializer. That means that I also need to pass a Course to the Itinerary's designated init. Therein lies the problem...when I try to reinitialize an itinerary from within the decodable initializer I don't have access to the course that the itinerary needs to be added to and so can't set the `course` property during initialization.

The issue seems to revolve around how I am attempting to initialize itineraries along with how I am attempting to manage the memory. A little research has pointed me in the direction of changing the course property either to an optional weak var, i.e. `weak var course: Course?` or marking it as an implicitly unwrapped optional, i.e. `var course: Course!`. Both of those options seem as though they may be introducing more complexity into the model than is necessary because of how I'll need to rewrite the Itinerary initializers. According to Apple's docs, it's appropriate to mark a property as unowned [when the other instance has the same lifetime or a longer lifetime](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ID54), which accurately describes the scenario here.

My question is sort of two-fold; there seems to be an inherent flaw with how I am attempting to initialize my model:

- If not, how would I go about reassembling my model when decoding? Do I need to reconsider my initialization logic?
- If so, what is the flaw? Am I using the right ARC strategy to manage the memory? Should I be considering a data structure other than JSON?

In the interest of brevity I excluded all the properties from the classes that seemed irrelevant. But I'll include more code if people feel it would be necessary to offer a complete solution.

Cliff notes of the important points:

- the desired JSON is produced w/ out encoding the `course` property of the Itinerary class.
- course's `addItinerary(_:)` func is when the itinerary's `course` property is set...it's called within Itinerary's designated init.
- BUT...I can't call that init while decoding because I never encoded a course...when I try to encode a course in the Itinerary's `encode(to:)`, Xcode throws BAD ACCESS  errors and points to an address in memory that I am unsure of how to debug.

  ```
  class Document: NSDocument {
      var masterCourseList = [Course]()
  }

  class Course: NSObject {
      // ...other properties
      private(set) var itineraries: [Itinerary]() {
          didSet {
              // sorting code
          }
      }

      func addItinerary(_ itinerary: Itinerary) {
          itinerary.course = self
          self.itineraries.append(itinerary)
      }

      // encodable conformance
      func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
          var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
          // ...encode other properties
          try container.encode(itineraries, forKey: .itineraries)
      }

      // decodable conformance
      required convenience init decode(from: Decoder) throws {
          let decoder = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
          // ...decode other properties
          let decodedItineraries = container.decode(Array<Itinerary>.self, forKey: .itineraries)

          self.init()

          for itinerary in decodedItineraries {
              self.addItinerary(itinerary)
          }
      }

      enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
          case itineraries, // other keys... //
      }
  }


  class Itinerary: NSObject {
      @objc dynamic let date: Date
      unowned var course: Course
      // ...other properties

      private init(date: Date, course: Course) {
          self.course = course
          self.date = date
          super.init()
          course.addItinerary(self)
      }

      // encodable conformance
      func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
          // ...encode all the desired properties of itinerary class
          // ...never encoded the 'course' property but still got the desired JSON file
      }

      // decodable conformance
      required convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
          // ...decode all the properties
          // ...never decoded the 'course' property because it was never encoded

          self.init(date: decodedDate, course: decodedCourse)
      }
  }
  ```

And a sample of the JSON that is being produced...

```
[
  {
    "itineraries" : [
      {
        "date" : 587357150.51135898
      },
      {
        "date" : 587443563.588081
      }
    ],
    "title" : "sample course 1",
    "startDate" : 587357146.98558402,
    "endDate" : 587789146.98558402
  },
  {
    "itineraries" : [
      {
        "date" : 587357150.51135898
      },
      {
        "date" : 587443563.588081
      },
      {
        "date" : 587443563.588081
      }
    ],
    "title" : "sample course 2",
    "startDate" : 587957146.98558402,
    "endDate" : 588389146.98558402
  }
]
```

Comment: People will have a tough time answering your question without seeing any JSON as far as I can tell. Please try to compose a relevant piece of JSON and edit your question to show it. I hope you can clarify the issue by doing so.

Comment: @Patru OK, thank you for the tip. I will get right to producing a valid JSON and update the post ASAP.

Comment: @Patru all set. I've added a block that illustrates the JSON that is produced. Again, that is the desired formatting

Comment: https://www.json4swift.com